# How to print stdout and stderr of a command with different colors in C langage

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am writing a program in C language that acts like a shell terminal, the user enters a command and I parse the line then use "execv()" to execute the command.

Now I'm trying to print the standard output and the error output with different colors (making sure that the order doesn't change. But I'm having troubles both outputs.

Thanks you for your help

```
void dumsh_execute(char **command_args, char **redirection_args) {

  if ( redirection_args[0]  ) {
    printf("%s\n", "Redirecting");
    if ( !redirection_args[1] ) {
      printf("%s\n", "redirection requiers a file path");
      return;
    }
  } else {

    if ( strcmp( command_args[0], "cd" ) == 0 ) {
      execute_cd( command_args );
    } else if ( strcmp( command_args[0], "clear" ) == 0 ) {
      execute_clear( command_args );
    } else if ( strcmp( command_args[0], "exit" ) == 0 ) {
      execute_exit( command_args );
    } else {

      int first_pipe[2];
      int second_pipe[2];
      if( pipe(first_pipe) == -1 || pipe(second_pipe) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");
      }

      pid_t pid = fork();

      if (pid == -1) {
        printf("Failed forking child..\n");
        return;
      } else if (pid == 0) {
        close(first_pipe[0]);
        close(second_pipe[0]);
        dup2(first_pipe[1], 1);
        dup2(second_pipe[1], 2);


        if (execvp(command_args[0], command_args) < 0) {
          printf("Could not execute command..\n");
          exit(0);
        }

        close(first_pipe[1]);
        close(second_pipe[1]);

      } else {
        close(first_pipe[1]);
        close(second_pipe[1]);

        fd_set rfds;
        int retval;

        /* Watch stdin (fd 0), stdout (fd 1) and stderr (fd 2) to see when it has I/O. */
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(first_pipe[0], &rfds);
        FD_SET(second_pipe[0], &rfds);

        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 2;
        timeout.tv_usec = 100000;

        retval = select(7, &rfds, 0, 0, &timeout);

        if (retval == -1) {
          perror("select()");
        } else if (retval) {


          if ( FD_ISSET(first_pipe[0], &rfds) ) {
            char msg[4024];
            while (read(first_pipe[0], msg, sizeof(msg)) > 0) {
              printf("\033[%sm%s", GREEN  , msg);
            }
          }
          if ( FD_ISSET(second_pipe[0], &rfds) ) {
            char msg[4024];
            while (read(second_pipe[0], msg, sizeof(msg)) > 0) {
              printf("\033[%sm%s", RED  , msg);
            }

          }
        }

        wait(NULL);
        close(first_pipe[0]);
        close(second_pipe[0]);
        return;
      }

    }

  }

}
```

This is the function that executes the command, but as you can see the close and dupe are a mess !

Comment: `if ( !redirection_args[0] ) {` can never be true, you checked it two lines before, are you missing an `else`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri you're totally right, I wanted to check [1] ... but don't mind that part, it's for another purpose. the real issue is in the else.

Comment: Built-in commands should be handled in the parent process without forking, not in the child.

Comment: @Barmar you're right, that makes more sense.

Comment: And if you want to process both stdout and stderr, you'll need to use `select()` or `epoll()` so you can wait for output on both FD's. Another problem you'll run into with this is that output to pipes is usually buffered.

Comment: @Barmar can you please elaborate, maybe a snippet of code ?

Comment: It's too much for a quick snippet. Research how to use `select()`.

Comment: @Barmar so if I understand what you said, I can use only slelect to monitor both stdout and stderr ... without using pipe and dupe2 ?

Comment: End your ANSI sequences with `\033[0m` to properly see portion of text in different colors. Example, `\033[31mYourMessage\033[0m`.

Comment: You should call `select()` only in the parent. There's also no need to put FD 0 (stdin) in the FD set.

Comment: @Barmar I just edited the code, It is necessary to use pipe and dup2, now the function works as expected, but when I type the command "ls -R /" is prints a lot of stdout and blocks !

Comment: Intercepting output of your child process is a rather bad idea. Many programs will change their behaviour or just stop working outright if you do that.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. would you please share a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what exact problem you mean. If the problem is that a child process blocks, it's probably because you are not using `select` correctly. You need to execute `select` with all its subordinare `read`s in a loop, and **not** execute subordinate `read`s in their own loops. Find an example program on the net. The other problem is that IMHO you simply should not try to intercept the output of the program, and if you accept that, you should simply throw away all the selects and dups and simply do fork-exec-wait like any good shell.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. But the objective of the assignment I have is to intercept both stdout and stderr and print them with different colors as well as respecting the order.